# Prove that a group built on a bijective function is a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $A \neq ∅$ be a set and $\mathcal{B}_A = \{f : A → A \;|\; f\;\mathrm{bijective}\}$.
Prove that $(\mathcal{B}_A, \circ)$  is a group.

I kind of understand how $\mathcal{B}_A$ is built but how am I supposed to prove that $(\mathcal{B}_A, \circ)$ is a group if I don't know anything about $\circ$

Comment: You are correct, if $\circ$ is undefined then you obviously can’t prove it is a group. However, $\circ$ is often defined as function composition. $(f\circ g)(a)=f(g(a)).$ Here, I think you can assume that definition.

Comment: The group is isomorphic to [the symmetric group on $A$.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#:~:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20the%20symmetric,is%20the%20composition%20of%20functions.)

Comment: Often it is written ${\rm Sym}(A)=\mathcal{B}_A = \{f : A → A \;|\; f\;\mathrm{bijective}\}$, which is the symmetric group on $A$ with composition of maps $f\circ g$. If "you don't know anything on $\circ$", then try to look up a context (like composition of maps etc.)

Comment: A group is an algebraic structure where the structure is determined by the binary operation . 

So, to prove some set form a group, you have to understand the operation first because the four group defining axioms are nothing but playing with the operation.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I actually didn't know what the $Sym(A)$ was and how it was built but now everything is clearer and actually the linked question answers mine. I guess I'll just leave the question here anyway for anyone who encounters my same problem and doesn't know $Sym(A)$

Comment: If the book where you took this exercise from does not define $\circ$, you should drop the book. If it did define it, you should delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here $\circ$ is composition of functions; that is, $(f\circ g)(a)=f(g(a))$ for all $a\in A$.

---

Let $a,b\in A$.

**Closure:**

For any $f,g\in \mathcal{B}_A$, we have that if $(f\circ g)(a)=(f\circ g)(b)$, then $f(g(a))=f(g(b))$ implies $g(a)=g(b)$, which, in turn, implies $a=b$. Thus $f\circ g$ is injective.

Consider again $a\in A$. Then there is some $b\in A$ such that $f(b)=a$ since $f$ is surjective. But then, similarly, there is some $c\in A$ such that $g(c)=b$. Hence $(f\circ g)(c)=f(g(c))=f(b)=a$. Thus $f\circ g$ is surjective.

Hence $f\circ g$ is bijective on $A$.

**Associativity** follows from associativity of functions.

The **identity** function

$$\begin{align}
{\rm id}_A: A&\to A,\\
a&\mapsto a,
\end{align}$$

is clearly the identity element in $\mathcal{B}_A$.

For **inverses**, let $f\in\mathcal{B}_A$. Then there exists
an $f^{-1}:A\to A$ such that $(f\circ f^{-1})(a)=a$ for all $a\in A$ since $f$ is a bijection. But then, by definition of ${\rm id}_A$, we have $f\circ f^{-1}={\rm id}_A$; similarly, $f^{-1}\circ f={\rm id}_A$.

Thus $(\mathcal{B}_A,\circ)$ is a group.